# How to truncate UITextView contents to fit a reduced size?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextview

I'm having real trouble getting my head around this issue.

As the title suggests, I have several UITextViews on a view in an iPhone application. I am programmatically creating them and successfully filling that textview with text, but in some cases the text I put in the view takes up more space than the frame I allocate for it. In this case I would like the text to be truncated, but I can't figure out how to do it.

I have predefined the following constants;

```
#define viewOriginX  20
#define viewOriginY 180
```

Here is my UITextView creation code;

```
textViewOne = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(viewOriginX, viewOriginY + 65, 280, 45];
textViewOne.delegate = self;
textViewOne.scrollEnabled = NO;
textViewOne.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
textViewOne.font = viewFont;
textViewOne.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
textViewOne.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
[self.view addSubview:textViewOne];
```

In some cases I have 15 to 20 lines of text in here and I would like to truncate it to 2 lines.

Can anyone help me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance! :D

Comment: Would a UILabel work for you instead? There you can set the numberOfLines property which I think would have the behavior you're looking for.

Comment: I don't see why not... The user will not be able to edit this text anyway, so that will probably work by the looks of the API documentation for that method. I will give it a go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a character count. For example, if you have UITextField like this:

```
+--------------------+
|This is a string in |
|a text view.        |
+--------------------+
```

you have something like 20 characters per line. If you know that number you can simply truncate your string by `-substringToIndex:` method.

```
int maxCharacters = 40; // change it to your max
if([myString length] > maxCharacters) {
    myString = [myString substringToIndex:maxCharacters];
}
```

---

You can also think about `UILabel`. Since you need only 2 lines of text, UILabel's `numberOfLines` property can solve your problem.

Comment: numberOfLines was what I was after, works really well! Thanks everyone!

Comment: Problem with this approach is that some characters are ticker than others, so it won't work if you have dynamic text.

Comment: Does not account for \n, which can exceed the vertical size long before the number of characters are exceeded.

Answer (score 43):

### Original Answer *(iOS 6 and below)*

Sadly, `UILabel` with `numberOfLines` wont do it if you need the view to be editable. Or you want `UITextView`'s (native) vertical alignment.

Here's an `NSString` category that deletes words from a string, according to it's size in a rect:

```
@interface NSString (StringThatFits)
- (NSString *)stringByDeletingWordsFromStringToFit:(CGRect)rect
                                         withInset:(CGFloat)inset
                                         usingFont:(UIFont *)font
@end

@implementation NSString (StringThatFits)
- (NSString *)stringByDeletingWordsFromStringToFit:(CGRect)rect
                                         withInset:(CGFloat)inset
                                         usingFont:(UIFont *)font
{
    NSString *result = [self copy];
    CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(rect.size.width  - (inset * 2), FLT_MAX);
    CGSize size = [result sizeWithFont:font
                           constrainedToSize:maxSize
                               lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    NSRange range;

    if (rect.size.height < size.height)
        while (rect.size.height < size.height) {

            range = [result rangeOfString:@" "
                                        options:NSBackwardsSearch];

            if (range.location != NSNotFound && range.location > 0 ) {
                result = [result substringToIndex:range.location];
            } else {
                result = [result substringToIndex:result.length - 1];
            }

            size = [result sizeWithFont:font
                            constrainedToSize:maxSize
                                lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
        }

    return result;
}
@end
```

For a `UITextView`, use an inset of 8 to account for the way UIKit draws them:

```
CGRect rect = aTextView.frame;
NSString *truncatedString = [theString stringByDeletingWordsFromStringToFit:rect
                                     withInset:8.f
                                     usingFont:theTextView.font];
```

### Updated Answer *(iOS 7)*

Now `UITextView` uses TextKit internally, it's much easier.

Rather than truncating the actual string, set the `text` (or `attributedText`) property to the whole string and truncate the amount of text *displayed* in the container (just like we do with `UILabel`):

```
self.textView.scrollEnabled = NO;
self.textView.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 0;
self.textView.textContainer.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
```

Comment: If my string is something like "Hello\nWorld\nWassup ?" there is no truncation, it will only displays "Hello\nWorld" without the "..." at the end

Comment: Try to set number of lines to something. it working for me when i set it to 2. It is rare case that you will know number of lines so this will not help to a lot of people...

Answer (score 1):

Because `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` is deprecated in iOS 7, I made a few changes:

```
- (NSString *)stringByDeletingWordsFromStringToFit:(CGRect)rect
                                     withInset:(CGFloat)inset
                                     usingFont:(UIFont *)font
{
    NSString *result = [self copy];
    CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(rect.size.width  - (inset * 2), FLT_MAX);
    if (!font) font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
    CGRect boundingRect = [result boundingRectWithSize:maxSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: font, } context:nil];
    CGSize size = boundingRect.size;
    NSRange range;

    if (rect.size.height < size.height)
        while (rect.size.height < size.height) {

            range = [result rangeOfString:@" "
                                    options:NSBackwardsSearch];

            if (range.location != NSNotFound && range.location > 0 ) {
                result = [result substringToIndex:range.location];
            } else {
                result = [result substringToIndex:result.length - 1];
            }

            if (!font) font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
            CGRect boundingRect = [result boundingRectWithSize:maxSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: font, } context:nil];
            size = boundingRect.size;
        }

    return result;
```

}

Comment: Can I ask why you don't just use the textView's textContainer properties to do the truncation for you (as per my amended answer above)? Only reason I can think you'd want to use this method is if you're having to support iOS 6 or before (in which case you have my deepest sympathies!)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a peace of code i wrote to truncate a string (by words) to fit a certain width and height:

```
- (NSString *)stringByTruncatingString:(NSString *)string toHeight:(CGFloat)height maxWidth:(CGFloat)width withFont: (UIFont *)font {

    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    NSDictionary *attrDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:font, NSFontAttributeName, paragraphStyle, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, nil];
    NSMutableString *truncatedString = [string mutableCopy];

    if ([string sizeWithAttributes: @{NSFontAttributeName: font}].height > height) {
        // this line is optional, i wrote for better performance in case the string is too big
        if([truncatedString length] > 150) truncatedString = [[truncatedString substringToIndex:150] mutableCopy];
        // keep removing the last word until string is short enough
        while ([truncatedString boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(width, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingTruncatesLastVisibleLine|NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:attrDict context:nil].size.height > height) {
            NSRange wordrange= [truncatedString rangeOfString: @" " options: NSBackwardsSearch];
            truncatedString = [[truncatedString substringToIndex: wordrange.location] mutableCopy];
        }
        // add elipsis to the end
        truncatedString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@...",truncatedString];
    }
    return truncatedString;
}
```

Usage:

```
NSString *smallString = [self stringByTruncatingString:veryBigString toHeight:65 maxWidth:200 withFont:[UIFont systemFontSize:14.0f]];
```