# UITextView text fitting size

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I've got UITextView with variable size. Depending on the size I want to use only the portion of the text (from long string) that could fit into the UITextView frame. I don't want to resize UITextView to fit the string, I don't want to change text size to fit the frame. I want to take as many characters from the text as I can possibily put into UITextView with given frame.

How can I do this? I'm stuck on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the proper solution for this issue here:
[How to truncate UITextView contents to fit a reduced size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057707/how-to-truncate-uitextview-contents-to-fit-a-reduced-size?rq=1)

It's the followben answer. Pitty it isn't accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
Truncate the string size to what ever you want. Here i am truncating to 20 letters

```
str = [str substringToIndex: MIN(20, [str length])];
```